# Delphi and IEnumVariant problems

Tags: delphi

Hello I have an `AxisRates` object which is a ActiveX collection of `Rate` objects, all is written in Delphi.
When I call this collection in VB, or C# with a code like that:

```
For Each objRate In objAxisRates
  rem do something
Next
```

At the first time it's ok, but nothing at the second time. I have traced in my code, and I see that the first time the `Get_NewEnum` is called and after the `Next` method. The second time the `Get_NewEnum` is called, and that's all!
In my code I first initialize `g_Rates` which is an `AxisRates` object:

```
g_Rates[i]:=TAxisRates.Create;
g_Rates[2].fcount:=0;
```

The `AxisRates` type is like that:

```
IAxisRates = interface(IEnumVARIANT)
['{1339E0E3-6FF7-4352-B6C4-1AEC52361915}']
function Get__NewEnum: IUnknown; safecall;
function Get_Count: Integer; safecall;
function Get_Item(Index: Integer): IRate; safecall;
property _NewEnum: IUnknown read Get__NewEnum;
property Count: Integer read Get_Count;
property Item[Index: Integer]: IRate read Get_Item; default;
end;

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf :    IAxisRatesDisp
// Indicateurs : (320) Dual OleAutomation
// GUID :        {1339E0E3-6FF7-4352-B6C4-1AEC52361915}
// *********************************************************************//
IAxisRatesDisp = dispinterface
['{1339E0E3-6FF7-4352-B6C4-1AEC52361915}']
property _NewEnum: IUnknown readonly dispid -4;
property Count: Integer readonly dispid 1;
property Item[Index: Integer]: IRate readonly dispid 0; default;
function Next(celt: LongWord; const rgvar: OleVariant; out pceltFetched: LongWord): HResult; dispid 1610678272;
function Skip(celt: LongWord): HResult; dispid 1610678273;
function Reset: HResult; dispid 1610678274;
function Clone(out ppenum: IEnumVARIANT): HResult; dispid 1610678275;
end;


type
TAxisRates = class(TAutoObject,IAxisRates,IEnumVariant)
private
  fIndex:integer;
protected
  function Get__NewEnum: IUnknown; safecall;
  function Get_Count: Integer; safecall;
{ Protected declarations }
{ IEnumVARIANT }
  function Next(celt: LongWord; var rgvar : OleVariant;
     out pceltFetched: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
  function Skip(celt: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
  function Reset: HResult; stdcall;
  function Clone(out Enum: IEnumVariant): HResult; stdcall;
 function Get_Item(Index: Integer): IRate; safecall;
public
  fCount,fAxe:integer;
  procedure Initialize; override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

And the code of `Get_NewEnum` and `Next` is:

```
function TAxisRates.Get__NewEnum: IUnknown;
begin
  result:=g_Rates;
  findex:=0;
end;

function TAxisRates.Next(celt: LongWord; var rgvar : OleVariant; out pCeltFetched : LongWord) : HRESULT;
var i:integer;
begin
  i:=0;
  while (i<integer(celt)) and (fIndex<fCount) do
  begin
    TVariantList(rgvar)[i]:=Get_Item(fIndex+1) as IDispatch;
    inc(i);
    inc(fIndex);
  end;
  if (@pCeltFetched <> nil) then pCeltFetched:=i;
  if i=integer(celt) then result:=S_OK else result:=S_FALSE;
end;
```

I don't understand where is my mistake, because it's running perfectly the first time and not the second :-(
Thank you for your help and sorry for my poor english.

Regards

Michel

Comment: That is true, but I have tried to!! Without result. In fact my problem is why does it work the first time, and not after :-(